# Python Gtk3, MessageDialog, default focused response after hiding dialog?

Tags: python, gtk3

after destroying dialog we can create new one with default focused response using `set_default_response` method. but when we hide dialog instead of destroying, this method does not work. how can I do this ?

example

```
#dialog variable is a GtkMessage dialog.
dialog.run()
dialog.hide()
dialog.run() # default focus doesn't work when we run dialog again after hiding.
```

Thanks.

**Note: sorry for asking questions frequently**

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen because the dialog widget will keep its state. This is the expected behavior. If you destroy and create a new one, it will be initialized.